# empty range in char class

Tags: php, regex

I have this script

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$yomi = 'アイウエオャュョハ゛ヒ゜';

if (mb_ereg('^[ヲ-゜]+$', $yomi)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

When I run it I get a warning:

[Warning]: mb_ereg(): mbregex compile err: empty range in char class

I googled but can't find a solution. Help please.

Comment: Your first character is `\u30F2` and the char after the hyphen is `\u309C` - the order is descending, while it must be ascending. What is your intention? Try to swap them and use `preg_match`: `preg_match('~^[゜-ヲ]+$~u', $yomi, $match)`

Comment: Just tried preg_match and get I get this: [Warning]: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 8 , Oh I see you update post, will try again

Comment: See my updated comment above - the range is out of order. What are you trying to match with your regex? Any Japanese character?

Comment: I need to check if strihg is half-size katakana or not in the system. I found that script in the net and they said that this script is checks that half-size katakana or not in the system.

Comment: Please check [this page](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094) - you might find your pattern or a hint there.

Comment: Also, try this one: [`^[\x{3040}-\x{309f}\x{30a0}-\x{30ff}]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/bU7mC7/1).

Comment: Could you check the unicode table and provide some feedback? What code points does the "half size Katakana" include? Your input seems to be Hirgana+Katakana. If you intend to match those, my above suggestion is valid.

Comment: I  did not work with unicode tables before and don't know how to check that.  I guess that hafl-width katakana symbols should take some range in this table but not sure.   I checked page you mentioned abot and took there regex for half-width katakana (ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ) I use it like this: mb_ereg('([ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ])', $yomi).  For 'アイウエオャュョハ゛ヒ゜' it gives false and for 'ｶﾀｶﾅ' it gives true which seems to be ok .  But still I'm not sure if its 100% proper validation. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Also I tried your regex and I get this error [Warning]: preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 9

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a **half-width katakana regex**, you can use the following validation:

```
preg_match('~^[ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ]*$~u', $yomi, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE3qF3/1)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/cIK0X1):

```
$re = "/^[ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ]*$/u"; 
$yomi = "アイウエオャュョハ゛ヒ゜";
$yomi2 = "ｶﾀｶﾅ"; 
if (preg_match($re, $yomi, $matches)) {
    echo "$yomi is valid!\n";
}
if (preg_match($re, $yomi2, $matches)) {
    echo "$yomi2 is valid!";
}
```

Output is only `ｶﾀｶﾅ is valid!`.

Comment: yes, that seems to work as expected. Will test more . Thank you for help !